# Crear select dinámicamente con javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de crear `select` en una lista dinámicamente, tengo los valores en un `array`.

```js
var ruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

function AddItem() {
 var tbody = null;
 var tabla = document.getElementById("tabla");
 var nodes = tabla.childNodes;
 for (var x = 0; x<nodes.length;x++) {
  if (nodes[x].nodeName == 'TBODY') {
   tbody = nodes[x];
   break;
  }
 }
 if (tbody != null) {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.innerHTML = `<td>
                    <select>
                    <option>Seleccionar</option>
                    </select>
                    </td>`;
  tbody.appendChild(tr);
 }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <table id="tabla">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Select</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 <button type="button" onClick="AddItem();">Agregar item.</button>
</form>
```

Mi problema es que el `select` creado dinámicamente tenga los valores del array intenté ponerlo en un foreach pero tampoco me funcionó.

Lo que trato de hacer es algo así:

```
tr.innerHTML = `<td>
                    <select>
                    ruits.forEach(function(element) {
                          <select>${element}</select>
                    });
                    </select>
                </td>`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
options = '<td>
                <select>';

ruits.forEach(function(item,index) {
                     options += '<option>' + item + '</option>';
                });

options += '</select>
            </td>';

tr.innerHTML = options;
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, tu respuesta fue sencillo, me solució un problemon.

Answer (score 3):

Hay una forma más simple de hacer esto:

1. Obtienes una referencia al `tbody` de la tabla
2. Empiezas a concatenar un elemento HTML completo que represente una fila
3. Le concatenas el `select` y sus `options` leyendo los valores del array con un `forEach`
4. Cierras cada elemento
5. Usas [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) para crear la nueva fila

Este es un código mucho más ligero, ya que no hace toda la lectura de cada elemento de la tabla para determinar el `tbody` de la misma.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

function AddItem() {

  var theBody = document.getElementById('tabla').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  var newRow = "<tr><td><select>";
  var theOptions = "";
  fruits.forEach(function(fruit) {
    theOptions += `<option value="${fruit}">${fruit}</option>`;
  });
  newRow += theOptions;
  newRow += "</select></td></tr>";

  theBody.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newRow);


}
```

```html
<form>
  <table id="tabla">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Select</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="button" onClick="AddItem();">Agregar item.</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
    <table id="tabla">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" onClick="AddItem();">Agregar item.</button>
</form>

<script>
    var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

    function AddItem() {
        var tbody = null;
        var tabla = document.getElementById("tabla");
        var nodes = tabla.childNodes;

        for (var x = 0; x < nodes.length; x++) {
            if (nodes[x].nodeName == 'TBODY') {
                tbody = nodes[x];
                break;
            }
        }

        if (tbody != null) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');            
            var opt = "";
            fruits.forEach(function (fruit) {
                opt = opt + '<option>' + fruit + '</option> ';                
            });
            tr.innerHTML = "<td><select>" + opt + "</select></td>";            
            tbody.appendChild(tr);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Espero te sirva